# How to get first integer between two specific characters with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, split, logfile

I'm parsing some log files and need to extract a integer for a "size" parameter.

The string (part of it) looks like this

```
 "asdasdasd\\\size\\x22:22\x0A23232d:123123123\x0A2"
```

I want to get the first integer between ":" and "\". That would be 22. Not 123123123.

I have tried the following code

```
 p = re.compile("[\:](\d+)[\D]")
 s = "asdasdasd\\size\\x22:22\x0A23232d:123123123\x0A2"
 p.findall(s)[0]

 output = '22'
```

However, if there is no number between the first appearances of ":" and "\" and want the code to return None or 0. Right now the code will return '123123123' if the pattern looks like this:

```
"asdasdasd\\size\\x22:\x0A23232d:123123123\x0A2"
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `re.search` with the following pattern:

```
p = re.compile(r"^[^:]*:(\d+)")
```

See the [regex demo with String 1](https://regex101.com/r/fragFx/2/) and another [demo with String 2](https://regex101.com/r/fragFx/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:]*` - 0+ chars other than `:`
- `:` - a `-`
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Frt2we):

```
import re
strs = ["asdasdasd\\size\\x22:\x0A23232d:123123123\x0A2", "asdasdasd\\\size\\x22:22\x0A23232d:123123123\x0A2"]
p = re.compile(r"^[^:]*:(\d+)")
for s in strs:
    result = ""
    m = p.search(s)
    if m:
        result = m.group(1)
    else:
        result = None
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
None
22
```